# How do you use rpmbuild to make an rpm package when there are file not found or permission errors?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to create an RPM file for the wget utility.  Both of my attempts (with sudo and without sudo) to use the rpmbuild comman fail to create an .rpm file.

I run a "sudo rpmbuild" command to use a spec file.  But I get these errors:

> error: File not found:
>   /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.19-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin/wget error:
>   File not found:
>   /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.19-1.x86_64/usr/local/share/man/man1/wget.1

If I manually create the directory paths and manually copy the files, I run into other problems down the road.  I think something is wrong if the rpmbuild command expects key files to be in the locations above.

I read it was recommended to not use sudo.  When I do not use sudo, the rpmbuild command (`rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/wget.spec`) shows this:

> Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NiuIFV
>   + umask 022
>   + cd /home/ec2-user/mywget/BUILD
>   + cd /home/ec2-user/mywget/BUILD
>   + rm -rf wget-1.19 rm: cannot remove 'wget-1.19/po/en@boldquot.header': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   'wget-1.19/po/zh_CN.po': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   'wget-1.19/po/id.gmo': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   'wget-1.19/po/gl.gmo': Permission denied ...

I see other "rm cannot remove ... Permission denied" lines.  I expected the rpmbuild command to work.  I have changed the permissions of the wget-1.19 folder to be 777 (via sudo chmod) with the owner and group being identical to the user running the rpmbuild command.  I still had the problem.

What can I do to create an RPM package of the wget utility?

```
# This is a sample spec file for wget

%define _topdir     /home/ec2-user/mywget
%define name            wget 
%define release     1
%define version     1.19
%define buildroot %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{version}-root

BuildRoot:  %{buildroot}
Summary:        GNU wget
License:        GPL
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source:         %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /usr
Group:          Development/Tools

%description
The GNU wget program downloads files from the Internet using the command-line.

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure
make

%install
make install prefix=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/local/bin/wget

%doc %attr(0444,root,root) /usr/local/share/man/man1/wget.1
```

The above was modified but heavily based on the spec file example here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/index.html

Comment: hard to say without seeing the contents of your `wget.spec` where did that file come from and how did you modify it?

Comment: As an aside, the reason you should never run `rpmbuild` as `root` / with `sudo`: If you do that, and the package goes rogue and installs something into `/usr/` instead of `$HOME/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/$PKG/usr/` during the build, it'll **succeed**. Then not only do you have a rogue file on your system, completely outside of `rpm`'s control, but that file also won't be included in the actual RPM.

Comment: (Quite a few Autotools and CMake projects accidentally go rogue on certain files, because they query `pkg-config` or Python `sysconfig` for the install destination and get an absolute path back. There's no `chroot` when running the `%install` step in `rpmbuild`, it relies on packages respecting build parameters like `PREFIX` and `DESTDIR` to redirect install locations.)

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> error: File not found:
>   /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.19-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin/wget

means that you specified this file in %files section:

```
%files
/usr/local/bin/wget
```

so rpmbuild is expecting this file in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/wget path but it is not there. Therefore this error. Vice versa for the man page.

You can run `rpmbuild -bi` which will stop just after `%install` phase and you can check the content of /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wget-1.19-1.x86_64/ where the `make install` actually put the files.

I *guess* that either

```
%install
make install prefix=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local
```

or

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/bin/wget
%doc %attr(0444,root,root) /usr/share/man/man1/wget.1
```

will fix your error. (just one of those!)